# Playing MP4 file in Powerpoint

Tags: ffmpeg, powerpoint, mp4, avi, wmv

I have a huge MP4 file (4GB) an hour long video. I want to extract port of the file. So I used the following command  to extract 70 seconds(00:01:10) of video  starting from 11 minutes

ffmpeg  -i   INPUT.mp4  -ss 00:11:00   -t 00:01:10 -c:v copy -c:a copy OUTPUT.mp4

Now I got a small file extracted from Input.MP4
The output.mp4 file size is still big(90 MB). So I used the following command

ffmpeg -i OUTPUT.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 30 SmallSizeVideo.avi

I got SmallSizeVideo.avi file which is approximately 6MB.

I am using Powerpoint 2010. I want to insert the video in Powerpoint and play.

Unfortunately when I embed SmallSizeVideo.avi Powerpoint is unable to play

1) Is my approach correct?
2) What is the best way to situation like me to play small portion of clips in powerpoint

Thank you

Comment: Please show the complete `ffmpeg` console output from your second command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last I heard, h.264 in avi was nonstandard. Try instead to output as mp4 and see if that plays in PowerPoint:

```
ffmpeg -i OUTPUT.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 30 SmallSizeVideo.mp4
```

If it works, I believe it may work in Windows 7 or later and also OS X.

Comment: Does _not_ work for me (Win7, 64 Bit, PowerPoint 2010).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to stay for PowerPoint 2010 at Windows 10. Thus, PowerPoint is unable to play MP4, cf. https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Video-and-audio-file-formats-supported-in-PowerPoint-d8b12450-26db-4c7b-a5c1-593d3418fb59. Finally, I come up with this command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -c:v wmv2 -b:v 12024k -c:a wmav2 -b:a 128k output.wmv
```

This command based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/34851916/2258393 by Reinhard Behrens.

By means of this command, I am able to archive the same file size and approx. the same quality as with MP4.